# Case insensitive autocomplete with Django

Tags: django, django-models, autocomplete

I'm using the jquery UI autocomplete widget in conjunction with Django to lookup 'tags' for a user to filter by. Our database saves tags exactly how the user entered them in the first place so 'test' and 'Test' are different; however in this autocomplete case I want the user to only see 'Test' when they type in 'te' to the autocomplete field.

Currently I'm using the following to return the list of possible tags:

```
tags = DBTag._model_class.objects.filter(tag__istartswith=term,author_token=self.my_token).distinct('tag')
found = [{'label':"%s" % tag.tag, 'value': "%s" % tag.tag} for tag in tags]
return to_json(found)
```

But this returns 'Test' and 'test'. Any thoughts?

EDIT: removed 'token' from the python loop since it is unneeded.

Comment: Do you specifically want the caps-first version, or do you just want one version of the tag?  Also, will the `tag.token` attribute be different for the two different test tags?

Comment: I would like one version of the tag (So the user only sees 'Test' rather than both 'test' and 'Test'). I could use python but am more interested in whether I can do it with some form of 'distinct' / model method.      In regards to the token, yes they will be different but that field is actually a relic and shouldn't be there. I do a separate call to pull down all items associated with the 'tag' so it is case insensitive at that point.

Comment: Hmm.  I was asking about `tag.token` because if you just need the `tag.tag` text, you could do this at the DB level by using `extra` to select the lowercased tag name, then use `values_list` to pull just that text.  If you also need the PK or other tag attributes, but want to get only one PK per lowercased tag name but also want to get multiple tags that contain the query as long as they don't share a name I think you're going to have to do it in Python.

Comment: For now what you describe initially will do the trick (I just need tag.tag text). If you have an example that would be great, but I'll go look up the docs too!

Comment: I've added an example as an answer - I don't have models handy that provide an exact test case, but it's working fine for returning things like unique lower-cased email addresses of my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get just the unique tag text matches, I think this should work:

```
tag_text = BGTag._model_class.objects.filter(tag__istartswith=term, author_token=self.my_token).extra(select={'lc_tag': 'LOWER(tag)'}).values_list('lc_tag', flat=True).distinct()
```